# How to read OTP from gmail in protractor?

Tags: javascript, email, protractor

Conf.js

How to read OTP from gmail. I tried but am not able to and also am not getting any error.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a few mail listener approaches for a cleaner solution, [inbucket](https://www.inbucket.org/) and [mail-listener2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener2) are two popular solutions for email reading purposes in e2e testing.

I would personally recommend inbucket for its simple implementation. You can run it as a docker container with a [simple command mentioned here](https://www.inbucket.org/binaries/docker.html), and then consume the exposed APIs using [this Javascript Client](https://github.com/Xotabu4/inbucket-js-client).

You can also use mail-listener2, it also offers the same functionality but requires a few configuration in the `.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I came up with. I made the assumption that the OTP is inside the first email in your inbox. It is also helpful to turn off the setting in gmail that allows similar messages to group together as this can cause issues. 
(Please pardon the use of browser.driver.sleep(), this can be replaced)

```
var tokenKey;
function getKey(a) {
// Open email from *******@gmail.com
// Its a non-angular site, so need to turn off synchronization
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.driver.sleep(3000);

// Opens a new tab in which you retrieve OTP
browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
  (function(a){
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.setAttribute('href', 'https://gmail.com');
  a.dispatchEvent((function(e){
    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    return e;
  }(document.createEvent('MouseEvents'))))}(document.createElement('a')));
});

browser.driver.sleep(3000);

// Switch to new tab
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
  browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]); 

  if(a){
    var username = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]'));
    username.sendKeys('*********@gmail.com');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('identifierNext')).click();
  }
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var firstEmail = element(by.xpath('//*[@id=":3d"]'));
    var passwordInput = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input'));

  if(a){
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(passwordInput), 5000);
    browser.driver.sleep(1000);
    passwordInput.sendKeys('*********');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('passwordNext')).click();
  }
      browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(firstEmail), 5000);
      firstEmail.click().then(function () {
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        element.all(by.cssContainingText('div', 'Text Leading up to password:')).count().then(function (results) {
          element.all(by.cssContainingText('div', 'Text Leading up to password::')).get(results-1).getText().then(function (token) {
            //console.log(token);
            tokenKey = token.substring(token.indexOf('-')+1, token.length);
            //console.log(tokenKey);
          });
        });
      });
  browser.driver.close();
  browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
});
}
```

Comment: I tried above code and not able to achieve it so can i give my gmail credentials so that you can try from your end. thanks

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: The var a represents whether this is the first time accessing the gmail on the current run. It skips the login aspect as the browser will remember that. You should be changing the following lines:

Comment: 1)username.sendKeys('*********@gmail.com');  2)passwordInput.sendKeys('*********');    3)element.all(by.cssContainingText('div', 'Text Leading up to password:')).count().then(function (results) {
4)element.all(by.cssContainingText('div', 'Text Leading up to password::')).get(results-1).getText().then(function (token) {
5)tokenKey = token.substring(token.indexOf('-')+1, token.length);        And maybe(I haven't needed to) 6)var firstEmail = element(by.xpath('//*[@id=":3d"]'));

Comment: username : testingavr@gmail.com and password : 12345678@ra

Comment: It says "Your password was changed 2 hours ago", did you post the correct information?

Comment: Even with test accounts, I would highly suggest not sending your email/password combination. This probably would of been better handled in a private chat.